# VS Code inferred type checking on React/Redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get some implicit type checking to work in VS Code. I have followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files), and it is catching type errors (i.e. I `let str = 'str'; str = 1;` would give a warning. However, it is also throwing errors on valid sections of code.

For example this line in a class that extends from React.Component throws an error:

`const { board } = this.props;`

Error:

```
[js] Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' 
has no property 'board' and no string index signature.
const board: any
```

Something similar is happening with this line:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Board);`

I would like to use inferred type checking, but not if it throws errors for valid code. Is there any way to achieve this?